# Python 3.8.5 already Installed but terminal uses 3.7.6 on typing python3

Tags: command-line, terminal, homebrew, macos-catalina, python-3.8

I will come straight to the point. I installed python version 3.8.5 as the latest stable python version but when I use the command python3 in my terminal it makes me use python 3.7.6.

Is there a way to fix this?

[screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jo393.png)

Comment: You should paste text as text, not as images. Also give some details like you OS version (macOS I guess), setting of `PATH`, maybe `which python`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the local of the new version to your PATH variable, and ensure the command s referring to the right file with

```
python3 —version
```

Check this out: https://superuser.com/questions/433897/python-in-command-line-runs-the-wrong-version